# Align text centered at bottom of webpage

Tags: css

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I want the footer centered at the bottom of the webpage but position seems to override text-align.

Comment: And certainly you should post the markup too, or even better: some fiddle to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `footer` element is a `block` element. Block elements take up the entire width of the container it's in.

However, when a block element is set to `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`, it'll shrink down to as small as it can get. By default, it's aligned to the left of the page.

Just add this style to your `footer`:

```
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center the `<footer>` element itself, you could do.

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g1xzvas2/)**

```css
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<footer>footer</footer>
```

If you only need to center the text inside, you can simply add `width:100%` to the `footer`, you should also add the missing `left:0`.

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g1xzvas2/1/)**

```css
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: No it's not, it has to be like that for centering the footer element itself, not only the text inside - watch the red borders I added there.

Comment: I mean the vendor prefixes. You could just use margin-left: -50%?